# Bootstrap row within nested column, responsive height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, flexbox

I am trying to have the gray text are fill the rest of the available space in this column while growing/shrinking with the window size (the remaining 100px or so). The bottom of the gray text area should be even with the large image on the left.

I was thinking there was a flexbox solution, but nothing seems to work well.

Maybe the solution is to remove the BS classes from the entire right column? and just write this section with more css?

[image: Mockup for design]

```css
img {width:100%}
.content-text {background:gray; margin-top:15px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="content-img" src="http://c7.staticflickr.com/9/8192/8086114606_c8b71f3277_b.jpg" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- col -->

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="content-box">
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="content-img" src="http://c5.staticflickr.com/8/7350/14012783868_630bff261c_b.jpg" alt="" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- col -->

                <div class="col-sm-6">

                    <div class="content-box">
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="content-img" src="http://c5.staticflickr.com/8/7350/14012783868_630bff261c_b.jpg" alt="" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- col -->

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="content-box">
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="content-text">
                                <p>hello world</p>
                            </div><!-- content-text -->
                        </div><!-- item -->
                    </div><!-- content-box -->
                </div><!-- col -->

                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <div class="content-box">
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="content-text">
                                <p>hello world</p>
                            </div><!-- content-text -->
                        </div><!-- item -->
                    </div><!-- content-box -->

                </div><!-- col -->

            </div><!-- row -->

        </div><!-- col -->

    </div><!-- row -->

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="placeholder-box"></div>

        </div><!-- col -->

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <div class="placeholder-box"></div>

                </div><!-- col -->

                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <div class="placeholder-box"></div>

                </div><!-- col -->

            </div><!-- row -->

        </div><!-- col -->

    </div><!-- row -->

</div><!-- container -->
```

Comment: What is the original code that didn't work? The above custom css you've added fills the entire row as you wanted.

Comment: fill the entire column * corrected in the description now

Comment: Can you provide an rough sketch or image showing what you want instead of the above?

Comment: added mockup for design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, not the best code i'm sure but that what i can think of now.
The solution is simple:

- Use flexbox to make first two col equal height
- Then make the container inside right col (which contain 2 small col - and i had modify your html structure here, hope it not go wrong with your intend) full height of the right col
- Add the background in one of the container
- Make the *content-text* area have border top to make it look like it seperate from the img.

That all, you can see it better in the code below. Hope it help!

```css
img {width:100%}
.content-box {background-color: gray}
.content-text {border-top:15px solid white;}
.row-eq-height {display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap}
.fullHeight {display: flex}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="content-img" src="http://c7.staticflickr.com/9/8192/8086114606_c8b71f3277_b.jpg" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- col -->

        <div class="col-md-6 fullHeight">
            <div class="row fullHeight">
                <div class="col-sm-6 fullHeight">
                    <div class="content-box fullHeight">
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="content-img" src="http://c5.staticflickr.com/8/7350/14012783868_630bff261c_b.jpg" alt="" />
                            </a>
                           <div class="content-text">
                                <p>hello world</p>
                            </div><!-- content-text -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- col -->

                <div class="col-sm-6 fullHeight">
                    <div class="content-box fullHeight">
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="content-img" src="http://c5.staticflickr.com/8/7350/14012783868_630bff261c_b.jpg" alt="" />
                            </a>
                           <div class="content-text">
                                <p>hello world</p>
                            </div><!-- content-text -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- col -->
            </div>
        </div><!-- col -->
    </div><!-- row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="placeholder-box"></div>
        </div><!-- col -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="placeholder-box"></div>
                </div><!-- col -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="placeholder-box"></div>
                </div><!-- col -->
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div><!-- col -->
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- container -->
```

Comment: The text area seems to behave the same as in my snippet.

Comment: @mattbtay sorry, not test in chrome; see again my edited answer